# Python beautiful soup code worked yesterday but gives an error message today

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I made a pretty basic web scraper using Python 3.6 that is designed to take a list of urls stored within a csv document and return information. Yesterday it was working.

Today, it's no longer working, even with the previously used csv of URLs.Instead I get an error message.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time


dataset = pd.read_csv('read_csv.csv')
dataset = dataset.iloc[:, 0].str.strip('[]')


data = []
for i in dataset:
    page = urlopen(i)
    soup = bs(page, 'html.parser', time.sleep(1))
    title = soup.find(attrs = {'class': 'title'})
    title = title.text.strip()
    content = soup.find(attrs = {'class': 'articleContent articleTruncate'}, itemprop = 'text')
    content = content.text.strip()
    date = soup.find(attrs = {'class': 'date'})
    date = date.text.strip()
    author = soup.find(attrs = {'class': 'authorInfo'})
    author = author.text.strip()
    data.append((title, date, author, content))
```

Here is the console error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-3a1fc158da11>", line 6, in <module>
    title = title.text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: That means that `title` has the value `None`, meaning it wasn't found. Perhaps the website you are scraping has changed.

Comment: That was my first thought too. I looked back at the html and nothing appears to have changed. The title is still under "class: title".

Comment: Can you please do some debugging first? Check which line is causing the problem, try printing the contents, and then post only that code with the exact issue. For which url is the problem occurring? You've not shared any url and we cannot reproduce any problem. Please create a [mcve].